# Using Erlang for testing.

Tags: erlang, smp

Can I test on a computer with a single core erlang programs for four or more cores?

When starting without using any parameter erlang smp assumes 2:2 like this:

`Erlang R14A (erts-5.8) [smp: 2:2] [rq: 2] [async-threads: 0]`

I am using a Pentium 4, does that mean I have two cores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default one scheduler is started per available core, and multi run-queues are used (one for each scheduler; available since R13). In your shell `[smp 2:2]` means that you have two schedulers running on two cores; `[rq: 2]` means you are using two run queues.

If you want to change the number of schedulers, start with `erl +S 4` for four schedulers for example.

Make sure that if you compile erlang on a single-core system, you enable smp in the configure script using `--enable-smp-support`. Otherwise you might not be able to use multiple schedulers.

Comment: I'm a little confused.

If I run erlang on a single core can use to simulate other quantities smp core?

For example if you run in single core 4 core simulating the time spent is the same as running straight into a 4 core?

You can do this test?

Comment: Each scheduler is a separate OS process, and by default one is started for each core. Running multiple schedulers is possible nevertheless, but of course this will not make your computer any "faster".

A single core machine is a special case, because if you build a VM without SMP, it might be a bit tweaked compared to SMP enabled machines (because of using less locks).